# Passing an array to a EJS view, using Bookshelf.JS

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, bookshelf.js

My logic:

```
/* GET /events/list */
router.get('/events/list', function(req, res) {

    new db.Tag({})
    .fetchAll()
    .then(function(tags) {

        res.locals.title = "List of events";
        res.locals.tags = tags;
        res.render('events/list.ejs');
    });
});
```

My view:

```
<% for (var tag in tags) { %>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
             <input type="checkbox" data-tag-id="<%= tag.tagId %>" />
             <%= tag.name %>
        </label>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

What I'm getting:

```
 [x] undefined
 [x] undefined
 [x] undefined
 [x] undefined
```

What I should be getting:

```
 [x] foo
 [x] bar
 [x] zort
 [x] troz
```

I also tried passing

```
 res.locals.tags = tags.toJSON();
```

and also

```
 res.locals.tags = JSON.stringify(tags);
```

So.. how do I finally pass my collection to an EJS view?

I also logged (`console.log(tags)`) just after `then(function(tags)` and I'm getting the models (tags in this case) correctly.

I also tried tags.forEach in my EJS view but a native javascript array like this: `[{tagId:1, name:"blah"}, {tagId:2, name"Foo"}]` doesn't have "forEach" method implemented

Comment: I think tags.toJSON() alters the collection "tags" instead of creating a copy of it

Comment: Have you tried passing the data in via `res.render` rather than `res.locals`?

Comment: @Owlvark no, how? (consider that in this post I'm passing only the tags variable, but in reality I'm passing more than one variable)

Comment: `res.render(view, [locals], callback)` (http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.render) where `[locals]` is a data object (your tags in this case).

Comment: I typically add things to locals from middlewhere that runs before the actual middlewhere shown here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your template, use forEach (if available) or loop using the index instead.

**server.js**

```
res.locals.tags = tags.toJSON();
```

**view.html (with `[].forEach`)**

```
<% tags.forEach(function(tag) { %>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
             <input type="checkbox" data-tag-id="<%= tag.tagId %>" />
             <%= tag.name %>
        </label>
    </div>
<% }) %>
```

**view.html (with indices)**

```
<% for (var i in tags) { %>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
             <input type="checkbox" data-tag-id="<%= tags[i].tagId %>" />
             <%= tags[i].name %>
        </label>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

Comment: I tried that (at the end of my post I mention about it), but it was telling me that "the object ... doesn't have foreach method" (because its a pure javascript array)

Comment: Really? Are you running an older version of node?Array.prototype.forEach is defined for me.

edit: [].forEach is also the reccomended practice in the ejs docs.

Comment: I dont think my node is an old version, I just install it some days ago. This is a weird problem because I was using sequelize.js instead of bookshelf.js and when I passed my results (tags) to the ejs view, I used tags.forEach without problems... now it was throwing that is not implemented when I previously did tags.toJSON();.  Without doing tags.toJSON() I do get 4 undefineds (4 is the number of tags)

Comment: How odd. Ok, here's what's happening: `for(var i in <<Array>>)` sets `i` to the index, not the value. So you could do `<%= tags[i].name %>` and get your result (although it's ugly). When you don't use `.toJSON`, you are passing a Bookshelf collection through, which implements its .forEach method (it uses underscore's).

Comment: I posted an alternate answer that doesn't rely on [].forEach.

Comment: Hey, what finally worked for me was: (1) serverside I used tags.toJSON(), (2) clientside: I used the information you gave me about "sets i to the index, not the value", that is: for (var i in tags), and then tags[i].name... so.. if you post that as an answer I can accept it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58029/discussion-between-sports-and-tuxedo25).

Comment: I went ahead and edited this answer to include the indices option.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative to using `Array.prototype.forEach`. You give the Bookshelf collection to the view. Bookshelf.Collection has its own `.forEach`:

**server.js**

```
res.locals.tags = tags; // NOT .toJSON()
```

**view.html**

```
<% tags.forEach(function(tag) { %>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
             <input type="checkbox" data-tag-id="<%= tag.id %>" />
             <%= tag.get('name') %>
        </label>
    </div>
<% }) %>
```

Comment: Hmm maybe this will work, using tag.get('name') and tag.id, but I don't like very much the idea of passing the entire Bookshelf model